# After reload page "Uncaught Error: Could not find Backbone. You must call adaptor.init(Backbone)"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ractivejs

Hi :) I use a ractiveJS and backboneJS in my app. For collaboration this lib I us a "ractive-adaptors-backbone.js". Whe I run app all works good but when I click in browser reload button and app is reload :) My dev environment is broken.

Console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find Backbone. You must call adaptor.init(Backbone) - see http://TKTKTK.com for more information
```

And more:

```
filter  @   ractive-adaptors-backbone.js?v=@@VERSION:29
```

Comment: Could you please post more code

Comment: Yes but in this app is 688 js files :P in AMD style.  I cen put console info.

http://www.beetxt.com/su8/

Comment: We only need to see the files related to the issue, else no one is going to be able to help you

Comment: I understand but in this issue error is in "ractive-adaptors-backbone.js" https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-adaptors-backbone/blob/master/dist/ractive-adaptors-backbone.js In my code is 1:1 this same code. And I don't know whot I can show You more :P